# Is there a way to control Apple Music streamed to my Google Home speaker groups from my phone?

Tags: iphone, music, apple-music

I'm trying to switch over from Spotify to Apple Music, but there's a missing feature that's a dealbreaker for me.  With Spotify, I can use the Spotify app on my iPhone to control music on a Google Home speaker group: search for songs, play, stop, etc.  The closest approximation I've been able to find with Apple Music is to enable one of my speakers as a Bluetooth speaker, but that doesn't let me control multiple speakers in a group at once.  Does this feature exist somewhere?

Comment: Spotify has features you want, Apple Music does not, so why switching to Apple Music?

Comment: @MarcWilson In other aspects I find Apple Music works better for me, but without this one feature it's no good.  I thought it worthwhile to ask if it exists before making my decision.